# Get variable of function within in same file in node.js

Tags: node.js, mongodb

i tried with this code but i can't get value of variable

```
var haveemail = 0; 

collection.count({email: req.body.email}, function (error, count,callback)                 { 
    console.log(count); 
    haveemail = count; 
}); 
console.log(haveemail)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Node.js works asynchronously, which means that right after `collection.count()` starts running, your `console.log()` call starts, most probably before the count call ends and before your variable is set.

you should move the console.log call to inside the callback, to make sure it happens after haveemail variable is set:

```
var haveemail = 0; 

collection.count({email: req.body.email}, function (error, count,callback) 
{ 
    console.log(count); 
    haveemail = count; 
    console.log(haveemail);
});
```

Comment: i agree with you , actually i want count value out side  collection.count  thats why i store count value in haveemail but i cant got it

Comment: @Dharmesh7980 - whatever you want to do with this variable outside the function - you have to do it inside, or use `promises` or `async` library. Otherwise you can't count on it to be set on time. See this guide, it's quite good: https://blog.risingstack.com/node-hero-async-programming-in-node-js/